# Viewing site in IE causes Quirks mode, making it unusable

Tags: css, quirks-mode

I tried looking for hours for a fix to this, and nothing has worked. I am trying to just build a menu bar, but it is not working correctly in IE (I test in IE7 and 8.) Everything opens IE in quirks mode. I have looked reasons as to the cause of this and tried everything I could where it is now beyond my understanding. I ran both the CSS and HTML files through the validation, and both came back with zero problems. I heard about hidden BOM characters aand white space before the doctype and ran both files through a detector, with both coming back fine. I apologize, but I am not as advanced as some on here, and thank ahead of time for any help. Any education as to what might be causing this would be appreciated. I cannot post the URL because this is an intranet site, so I will just post the code I'm using.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<title>Mega Drop Down Menu</title>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style>
body {behavior: url("csshover3.htc");}
#menu li .drop {background:url("img/drop.gif") no-repeat right 8px; 
</style>
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="#" class="drop">Home</a>

        <div class="dropdown_2columns">

            <div class="col_2">
                <h2>Welcome !</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_2">
                <p>Hi and welcome here ! This is a showcase of the possibilities of this awesome Mega Drop Down Menu.</p>             
                <p>This item comes with a large range of prepared typographic stylings such as headings, lists, etc.</p>             
            </div>

            <div class="col_2">
                <h2>Cross Browser Support</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <img src="img/browsers.png" width="125" height="48" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <p>This mega menu has been tested in all major browsers.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="drop">5 Columns</a>

        <div class="dropdown_5columns">

            <div class="col_5">
                <h2>This is an example of a large container with 5 columns</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <p class="black_box">This is a dark grey box text. Fusce in metus at enim porta lacinia vitae a arcu. Sed sed lacus nulla mollis porta quis.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <p>Phasellus vitae sapien ac leo mollis porta quis sit amet nisi. Mauris hendrerit, metus cursus accumsan tincidunt.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <p class="italic">This is a sample of an italic text. Consequat scelerisque. Fusce sed lectus at arcu mollis accumsan at nec nisi porta quis sit amet.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <p>Curabitur euismod gravida ante nec commodo. Nunc dolor nulla, semper in ultricies vitae, vulputate porttitor neque.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">
                <p class="strong">This is a sample of a bold text. Aliquam sodales nisi nec felis hendrerit ac eleifend lectus feugiat scelerisque.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col_5">
                <h2>Here is some content with side images</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_3">

                <img src="img/01.jpg" width="70" height="70" class="img_left imgshadow" alt="" />
                <p>Maecenas eget eros lorem, nec pellentesque lacus. Aenean dui orci, rhoncus sit amet tristique eu, tristique sed odio. Praesent ut interdum elit. Sed in sem mauris. Aenean a commodo mi. Praesent augue lacus.<a href="#">Read more...</a></p>

                <img src="img/02.jpg" width="70" height="70" class="img_left imgshadow" alt="" />
                <p>Aliquam elementum felis quis felis consequat scelerisque. Fusce sed lectus at arcu mollis accumsan at nec nisi. Aliquam pretium mollis fringilla. Nunc in leo urna, eget varius metus. Aliquam sodales nisi.<a href="#">Read more...</a></p>

            </div>

            <div class="col_2">

                <p class="black_box">This is a black box, you can use it to highligh some content. Sed sed lacus nulla, et lacinia risus. Phasellus vitae sapien ac leo mollis porta quis sit amet nisi. Mauris hendrerit, metus cursus accumsan tincidunt.Quisque vestibulum nisi non nunc blandit placerat. Mauris facilisis, risus ut lobortis posuere, diam lacus congue lorem, ut condimentum ligula est vel orci. Donec interdum lacus at velit varius gravida. Nulla ipsum risus.</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="drop">4 Columns</a>

        <div class="dropdown_4columns">

            <div class="col_4">
                <h2>This is a heading title</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <h3>Some Links</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <h3>Useful Links</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <h3>Other Stuff</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">FreelanceSwitch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Creattica</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WorkAwesome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mac Apps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Apps</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <h3>Misc</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

        </div>

    </li>

    <li class="menu_right"><a href="#" class="drop">1 Column</a>

        <div class="dropdown_1column align_right">

                <div class="col_1">

                    <ul class="simple">
                        <li><a href="#">FreelanceSwitch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Creattica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WorkAwesome</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mac Apps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Web Apps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">NetTuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">VectorTuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PsdTuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PhotoTuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ActiveTuts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
                    </ul>   

                </div>

        </div>

    </li>

    <li class="menu_right"><a href="#" class="drop">3 columns</a>

        <div class="dropdown_3columns align_right">

            <div class="col_3">
                <h2>Lists in Boxes</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <ul class="greybox">
                    <li><a href="#">FreelanceSwitch</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Creattica</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">WorkAwesome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mac Apps</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Web Apps</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <ul class="greybox">
                    <li><a href="#">ThemeForest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GraphicRiver</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ActiveDen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">VideoHive</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3DOcean</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

            <div class="col_1">

                <ul class="greybox">
                    <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Flash</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Illustration</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">More...</a></li>
                </ul>   

            </div>

            <div class="col_3">
                <h2>Here are some image examples</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="col_3">
                <img src="img/02.jpg" width="70" height="70" class="img_left imgshadow" alt="" />
                <p>Maecenas eget eros lorem, nec pellentesque lacus. Aenean dui orci, rhoncus sit amet tristique eu, tristique sed odio. Praesent ut interdum elit. Maecenas imperdiet, nibh vitae rutrum vulputate, lorem sem condimentum.<a href="#">Read more...</a></p>

                <img src="img/01.jpg" width="70" height="70" class="img_left imgshadow" alt="" />
                <p>Aliquam elementum felis quis felis consequat scelerisque. Fusce sed lectus at arcu mollis accumsan at nec nisi. Aliquam pretium mollis fringilla. Vestibulum tempor facilisis malesuada. <a href="#">Read more...</a></p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </li>


</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

The CSS here

```
body, ul, li {
    font-size:14px; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:21px;
    text-align:left;
}

#menu {
    list-style:none;
    width:940px;
    margin:30px auto 0px auto;
    height:43px;
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;

    /* Rounded Corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #014464;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0272a7, #013953);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0272a7), to(#013953));

    /* Borders */

    border: 1px solid #002232;

    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px #edf9ff;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

#menu li:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    padding: 4px 9px 4px 9px;

    /* Background color and gradients */

    background: #F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));

    /* Rounded corners */

    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#menu li a {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px; 
    color: #EEEEEE;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}

#menu li:hover a {
    color:#161616;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}
#menu li .drop {
    padding-right:21px;
    background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
}
#menu li:hover .drop {
    background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 7px;
}

.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    margin:4px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px 5px 10px 5px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    border-top:none;

    /* Gradient background */
    background:#F4F4F4;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEEEEE, #BBBBBB);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEEEEE), to(#BBBBBB));

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
.dropdown_5columns {width: 700px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

.col_1,
.col_2,
.col_3,
.col_4,
.col_5 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.col_1 {width:130px;}
.col_2 {width:270px;}
.col_3 {width:410px;}
.col_4 {width:550px;}
.col_5 {width:690px;}

#menu .menu_right {
    float:right;
    margin-right:0px;
}
#menu li .align_right {
    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

#menu li:hover .align_right {
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

#menu p, #menu h2, #menu h3, #menu ul li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:21px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu h2 {
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
}
#menu h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:7px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #888888;
}
#menu p {
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}

#menu li:hover div a {
    font-size:12px;
    color:#015b86;
}
#menu li:hover div a:hover {
    color:#029feb;
}


.strong {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.italic {
    font-style:italic;
}

.imgshadow { /* Better style on light background */
    background:#FFFFFF;
    padding:4px;
    border:1px solid #777777;
    margin-top:5px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #666666;
}
.img_left { /* Image sticks to the left */
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin:5px 15px 5px 5px;
}

#menu li .black_box {
    background-color:#333333;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    /* Shadow */
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}

#menu li ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
#menu li ul li {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    width:130px;
}
#menu li ul li:hover {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#menu li .greybox li {
    background:#F4F4F4;
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    width:116px;

    /* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#menu li .greybox li:hover {
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding:4px 6px 4px 6px;
    margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me as well with one of the websites I manage, everything passed validation from the W3C, the Web Developer plugin for Firefox reported no issues and yet we were seeing IE go into quirks mode...that is, until we added this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: Hi, I added this tag, and same situation. Do I replace the meta tag that is already present?

Comment: @user1751471, no, it should be in addition to your Content-type meta tag. When you say that your menu bar "is not working" in IE7/8, what exactly isn't happening that you expect/see in other browsers?

Comment: in IE, all I can see is the layout without the colors, its just a black box with white background, whereas the true bar is blue, and there is no functionality, such as the drop downs.

Comment: I think something else is going on...I was able to view your code in IE 7/8/9 just fine, and the dropdowns worked for me.

Comment: Well thank you for testing that. No one in my company runs IE9, just 7/8. I've tried testing this on multiple comps. So I'm not sure it's a setting thing. This is for an intranet, could that be an issue? I would think not. Are there possibly some CSS elements that are not compatible with IE 7/8. I'm not sure that is it either since it was working under your IE. I might just have to scrap it and look for something else.

Comment: I actually just noticed, and I probably should have checked this before, but when I load our intranet main page (Not the one I am working on) it puts IE into Quirks mode, so it might not just be my code.

Comment: Ya, not sure about how your intranet was configured, but I took your exact code and added it to my localhost.  When I loaded the page, it came up in quirks mode in IE9, but as soon as I added the meta tag in my answer and reloaded the page, it left quirks mode.  Both cases the dropdown menu works fine and looks good.

Comment: It's beyond me how it was configured. Would this meta tag need to be under our main index, or just being under my code should override it and put it into Standards mode when coming to this page?

Comment: I put it as the first meta tag on every page where you don't want to go into quirks mode (usually in a shared header so that I just have to update once)

Comment: Well... When I bring up the dev tools, I do not see the meta tag that I entered in the code. Here are a few screen shots of the HTML and Script views under dev tools.

Comment: Well... When I bring up the dev tools, I do not see the meta tag that I entered in the code. Here are a few screen shots of the HTML and Script views under dev tools.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/3gzjp  - HTML

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/wekug  - Script


Could this be the web dev tool we use is causing IE to use Quirks mode, theoretically causing the CSS3 aspects to not work properly?

Thank you for all the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: The code up top is the same when I enter it in under our web dev tool. It seems to even change the doctype to HTML 4.0.

Comment: @user1751471, I'd probably open up a separate ticket on SO because the screenshots you sent include totally different code than what your question is about.  StackOverflow is meant to help with specific questions and this discussion beyond my answer has kinda gotten out of control ;)  I think I've answered the question that you posed originally?

Comment: It lead me to answers as to why, and the understanding it might be out of my control to fix. So in conclusion yes. The code is different than my question because its being automatically entered. I believe I will just scrap the idea, and look for other conclusions,but thanks to you, I learned a great deal, so thank you. Sorry if this got out of hand.